# Bazel local JDK permission issue on Jenkins (Linux, CentOS)

Tags: bazel, bazel-java

I'm seeing a weird permission issue on Jenkins with Bazel. The build is using a CentOS based docker image that I am preparing.

```
21:56:37  + bazel build //src/main/java:HelloWorld
21:56:42  2021/11/10 20:56:42 Downloading https://releases.bazel.build/4.2.1/release/bazel-4.2.1-linux-x86_64...
21:56:48  Extracting Bazel installation...
21:56:49  Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
21:56:51  Loading: 
21:56:51  Loading: 0 packages loaded
21:56:51  Loading: 0 packages loaded
21:56:53  Loading: 0 packages loaded
21:56:53  Analyzing: target //src/main/java:HelloWorld (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
21:56:55  Analyzing: target //src/main/java:HelloWorld (10 packages loaded, 18 targets configured)
21:56:55  Analyzing: target //src/main/java:HelloWorld (21 packages loaded, 285 targets configured)
21:56:57  Analyzing: target //src/main/java:HelloWorld (21 packages loaded, 285 targets configured)
21:56:58  Analyzing: target //src/main/java:HelloWorld (21 packages loaded, 285 targets configured)
21:56:59  Analyzing: target //src/main/java:HelloWorld (22 packages loaded, 322 targets configured)
21:57:02  Analyzing: target //src/main/java:HelloWorld (22 packages loaded, 322 targets configured)
21:57:02  INFO: Analyzed target //src/main/java:HelloWorld (23 packages loaded, 454 targets configured).
21:57:02  INFO: Found 1 target...
21:57:03  [0 / 4] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
21:57:05  ERROR: /home/jenkins/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jenkins/61c828dc7f69c1411a6e2ba3a115033a/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/BUILD:346:14: Action external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/platformclasspath.jar failed: missing input file 'external/local_jdk/lib/jfr/MethodAndContention.jfc', owner: '@local_jdk//:lib/jfr/MethodAndContention.jfc': /home/jenkins/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jenkins/61c828dc7f69c1411a6e2ba3a115033a/external/local_jdk/lib/jfr/MethodAndContention.jfc (Permission denied)
21:57:05  Target //src/main/java:HelloWorld failed to build
21:57:05  Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
21:57:05  ERROR: /home/jenkins/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jenkins/61c828dc7f69c1411a6e2ba3a115033a/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/BUILD:346:14 Action external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/platformclasspath.jar failed: 1 input file(s) do not exist
21:57:05  INFO: Elapsed time: 18.036s, Critical Path: 1.11s
21:57:05  INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 linux-sandbox.
21:57:05  FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
21:57:05  FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

The `.bazelrc` contains:

```
# use the JDK available in Jennkins for everything
build --host_java_toolchain=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_java11
build --java_toolchain=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_java11
```

What I'm trying to understand is the lack of permissions. The `/home/jenkins` folder is the user home directory of the Jenkins user. It has full read/write permissions there.

`JAVA_HOME` is set to an Azul OpenJDK build. It's confirmed to work.

Any ideas what I should check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the obvious and added the following to lines to the `Dockerfile` creating the build container.

```
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins ${JAVA_HOME}
```

Obviously some permissions aren't ok with the default setup. Now I get passed the issue.